# Can't save updates in custom profile

Tags: python, django

I have custom Profile model and forms, that extends user information and let update first name, last name and E-Mail.

When I tried to update additional fields (balance), all works good. But when I tried to update first name, last name and E-Mail - it doesn't change after save...

And, also, picture in additional field doesn't save too (I dont't know, is that same problem or not).

What I'm doing wrong?

My model `userprofile`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import PIL

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
    user_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles', blank=True, null=True)
    user_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u) [0])
```

My `forms.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']

def save(self, *args, **kw):
    super(CustomUserForm, self).save(*args, **kw)
    self.instance.user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    self.instance.user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
    self.instance.user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    self.instance.user.save()
```

My `views.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

# Create your views here.
from userprofile.forms import CustomUserForm
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

def user_profile(request):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get()

    template = 'profile.html'

    if request.POST:
        form = CustomUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CustomUserForm(
            instance=profile,
            initial={
                'first_name': profile.user.first_name,
                'last_name': profile.user.last_name,
                'email': profile.user.email,
            })

    return render_to_response(template, {'form': form, 'profile': profile}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And `template`

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.error }}

{% endfor %}

<form action="/users/profile/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_ul }}

<input type="submit" value="Update" />

</form>
```

EXAMPLE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()

class CustomUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean_first_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']

def save(self, *args, **kw):
    super(CustomUserForm, self).save(*args, **kw)
    self.instance.user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    self.instance.user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
    self.instance.user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    self.instance.user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't work when you update firstname and lastname then the problem might reside in the validation of the form.

it is valid when left blank (which corresponds to your model), and it's not when you add input. So maybe the input has to be cleaned. Try to clean each field apart using def clean_fieldname method under your form. (clean_fieldname is triggered by form.is_active)

i think that there is no need to override save. Focus on your cleaning your fields.

try this for your fields:

```
  def clean_first_name(self):
    fn =self.cleander_data.get('first_name')
    if not fn:
       raise forms.ValidationError(_("Give a first name"), code='invalid')
    return fn
  def clean_last_name(self):
    ln =self.cleaner_data.get('last_name')
    if not ln:
       raise forms.ValidationError(_("Give a last name"), code='invalid')
    return ln
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

    if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This adress already exists"), code='invalid')
    return email
```

Comment: Thx one more time, but still all doesn't work - email, fname and lname doesn't save with that form...:(

Comment: try to figure out if your function save() is triggered or not. and try it with deleting the def save: in form (i think you don't need it)